# What regex do I use in jQuery to validate case insensitivity?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using a regex pattern match to validate some fields. For instance a State text box. I want to allow case insensitivity, but when I use `(?i)`, it monkeys up the validate and chrome Dev Tools tells me:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: 
/^(?i)(?:(A[KLRZ]|C[AOT]|D[CE]|FL|GA|HI|I[ADLN]|K[SY]|LA|M[ADEINOST]|N[CDEHJMVY]|O[HKR]|P[AR]|RI|S[CD]|T[NX]|UT|V[AIT]|W[AIVY]))$/: 
Invalid group
```

I've tested it on https://regex101.com/ and it works perfectly. If I remove the `(?i)`, it works (but it becomes case-sensitive).

How can I have a case-insensitive regex, without the use of `(?i)`?

Comment: `/regex/i` ...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm probably missing something, but...why can't you add the "i" at the end?

```
/^(?:(A[KLRZ]|C[AOT]|D[CE]|FL|GA|HI|I[ADLN]|K[SY]|LA|M[ADEINOST]|N[CDEHJMVY]|O[HKR]|P[AR]|RI|S[CD]|T[NX]|UT|V[AIT]|W[AIVY]))$/i
```

Comment: Well.... That'd be because I had no idea I could do that... :) As soon as the 10-minute timer is gone, this will be the answer. :)

Comment: PS You can also create a case-insensitive regular expression this way: new RegExp(/yourexpression/, "i")